How can I scale an Avalonia.UI App for high DPI Displays?
Yes, 4 years somebody asked the exact same question (Avalonia UI Scaling Issues) but maybe now it's possible to scale an Avalonia ui app. Cause when running my app on a 2.8 K display (Fedora 41 KDE Plasma) it's not scaled at all, all ui elements are extremely small. However when running on a FHD Screen, everything works fine.
Chat GPT said something like
AppBuilder.Configure<App>()
    .UsePlatformDetect()
    .With(new Win32PlatformOptions
    {
        RenderScalingFactor = 2.0 // Erzwungener Skalierungsfaktor (z. B. für 2.8K-Displays)
    })
    .With(new X11PlatformOptions
    {
        RenderScalingFactor = 2.0 // Gleicher Faktor für Linux
    })
    .StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);

...but these methods don't exist.
Thanks for helping out!
